# Powershell remote authenticate & application installation

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-remoting

I want to install applications on multiple remote machines.

`invoke-command -computer 10.13.14.10 -scriptblock {\\publicshare\software.msi /quiet}`

I am running this command from my local machine logged in as my user privileges, seems like I have to execute this as a higher privileges user (domain admin). How do I do that?

Error - `[10.13.14.10] Connecting to remote server failed with the following error message : The WinRM client cannot process the request. Default authentication 
may be used with an IP address under the following conditions: the transport is HTTPS or the destination is in the TrustedHosts list, and explicit creden
tials are provided. Use winrm.cmd to configure TrustedHosts. Note that computers in the TrustedHosts list might not be authenticated. For more informatio
n on how to set TrustedHosts run the following command: winrm help config. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (:) [], PSRemotingTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PSSessionStateBroken`

Answer (score 0):

To execute this command with another user, simply use the credential switch. So run your command as follows:

```
invoke-command -computer 10.13.14.10 -scriptblock {\\publicshare\software.msi /quiet} -Credential $(Get-Credential)
```

This will give you a user/password prompt and you can enter the details of the user that has access.

There might also be a problem with WinRM itself, are you sure you've configured it properly on the remote machine? run `winrm quickconfig` to ensure that it has been configured.

Answer (score 0):

It looks just like what the error says, your user need to be trusted (present in the TrustedHost list in 10.13.14.10) for delegation. Please refer the following links for more information.

- [How do I configure accounts so that
  they are trusted for delegation in a
  Windows Server 2003 Enterprise
  Edition environment?](http://www.windowsitpro.com/article/tips/jsi-tip-7359-how-do-i-configure-accounts-so-that-they-are-trusted-for-delegation-in-a-windows-server-2003-enterprise-edition-environment-)
- [Kerberos
  authentication and troubleshooting
  delegation issues](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/907272)

You can even have a look for the `winrm help config` command to have more idea on this.